# npm ERR! errno -4058

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am having this error when starting npm start, it seems that it is not finding the file `package.json`.
But I'm not sure if that's right, could someone help me?

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Projetos\omnistack\aulas\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Projetos\omnistack\aulas\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Thiago Magalhães\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-26T22_51_26_639Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Please share your `package.json` file or at least the `scripts` section. Also what folder are you running in?

Comment: Resolved friend, it was just the folder in which I was running that was wrong!